# jQuery does not run functions (animate, css) after second click but console.log works?

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$('.navigation a').on('click', function() {

        $('.navigation').mouseleave(function() {
            $('.navigation a').not('.bold').delay(2000).animate({opacity : 0}, 800, (function(){
                $(this).css({'visibility': 'hidden'});
            }));
        });

        $('.navigation').mouseenter(function() {
            $('.navigation a').css({visibility: 'visible'});
            $('.navigation a').animate({opacity : 1}, 800);
            console.log('asdfasd');
        });
});
```

The html:

```
<div class="navigation">
    <p class="header">BLANC+ENÇENS</p>
    <ul class="list">
        <li><a alt="BLANC+ENÇENS PROFILE" href="/profile">BLANC+ENÇENS PROFILE</a></li>
        <li><a alt="BLANC+ENÇENS SERVICES" class="on2" href="/services">BLANC+ENÇENS SERVICES</a>
            <ul class="hide sub first list">
                <li class="long"><a alt="BRAND CONSULTATIONS & STRATEGY" class="keep" href="/consultations">BRAND CONSULTATIONS & STRATEGY</a></li>
                <li><a alt="STRATEGIC PARTNERSHIPS" href="/partnerships">STRATEGIC PARTNERSHIPS</a></li>
                <li><a alt="INVESTMENT" href="/investment">INVESTMENT</a></li>
                <li><a alt="SALES" href="/sales">SALES</a></li>
                <li><a alt="PR" href="/pr">PR</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>   
        <li><a alt="BLANC+ENÇENS INSTRUCTION" class="on" href="/instruction">BLANC+ENÇENS INSTRUCTION</a>
            <ul class="hide sub first right list">
                <li class="long2"><a alt="LEGAL TERMS" class="keep" href="/terms">LEGAL TERMS</a></li>
                <li><a alt="IMPRINT" href="/imprint">IMPRINT</a></li>
                <li><a alt="DOWNLOAD" href="/download">DOWNLOAD</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>   
        <li><a alt="EFLÈ . FERDLÈ" href="/efleferdle">EFLÈ . FERDLÈ</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="animate list">
        <li><a alt="FASHION" href="/fashion">FASHION</a>
            <ul class="hide sub fashion list">
                <li><a alt="BROWNIE AND BLONDIE" href="/brownieandblondie">BROWNIE AND BLONDIE</a></li>
                <li><a alt="DIETRICH EMTER" href="/dietrichemter">DIETRICH EMTER</a></li>
                <li><a alt="LEVER COUTURE" href="/levercouture">LEVER COUTURE</a></li>
                <li><a alt="OLIVER RUUGER" href="/oliverruuger">OLIVER RUUGER</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a alt="LUXURY" href="/luxury">LUXURY</a></li>
        <li><a alt="ART" href="/art">ART</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="animate list lower">
        <li><a alt="INVESTORS" href="/investors">INVESTORS</a></li>
        <li><a alt="NEWS" href="/news">NEWS</a></li>
        <li><a alt="CONTACT" href="/contact">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I click once, the code works, after the second click, the `.mouseenter` function with `.animate()` and the `.css()` does not work anymore, but the `console.log()` runs. Why?

See it as example here: http://liebdich.biz/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you click you add a new copy of your event handlers for mouseenter and mouseleave so you then have multiple copies of them running at the same time.  That will cause problems.

If you describe what you're trying to achieve and show the relevant HTML, we could probably suggest a correct way to do this.

If you just want the behavior to start on first click, then you can probably do this:

```
$('.navigation a').on('click', function() {

    // get the navigation parent
    var parent = $(this).closest('.navigation');

    // check to see if the event handlers have already been installed
    if (!parent.data("handlersInstalled")) {
        parent.mouseleave(function() {
            $('.navigation a').not('.bold').stop(true).delay(2000).animate({opacity : 0}, 800, function(){
                $(this).css({'visibility': 'hidden'});
            });
        }).mouseenter(function() {
            $('.navigation a').css({visibility: 'visible'});
            $('.navigation a').stop(true).animate({opacity : 1}, 800);
            console.log('asdfasd');
        });
        // mark that we've installed handlers
        parent.data("handlersInstalled", true);
    }
});
```

I've made several changes here:

1. The event handlers are only ever installed just once on each object
2. They are only installed on the parent of the item we clicked on (not all items in the apge)
3. I added `.stop()` to the animations so animations won't pile up if the mouse is moved quickly
4. Use event chaining for calling multiple methods on the same jQuery object

Comment: Ok, I see, how can I make it differently? That the fade out occurs only after the first click? Thank you!

Comment: @dollarvar - please describe the whole behavior you're trying to create.

Comment: Please go onto the link, there the behavior works (on the first click). ;) Thanks!!

Comment: @dollarvar - I added a code suggestion to my answer and an explanation for what I changed.

Comment: Thank you!! But I just had another idea, on click I create variables with a function (the `.mouseenter` and `.mouseleave`) and call the function by name then on `.mouseenter` and `.mouseleave`. What do you say?

Comment: @dollarvar - you will need to provide a demo.  I don't have an easy way of testing it.  What does not work.  Does the browser error console or debug console show any script errors?

Comment: I could upload it, but the behavior is the same as before. ;) Let me test the new one! Thank you!!

Comment: @dollarvar - I removed some extra parens you had in the code.

Comment: This code works, excellent!! I learned a lot ( better said, I have now to learn what you gave me ;) )! Thank yous!!!

Comment: Hey jfriend00, what does the `true` mean on the `data` set? Greetings!!

Comment: @dollarvar - I'm using "handersInstalled" as a flag.  If the flag `.data("handlersinstalled")` doesn't exist, it will return `undefined` and `if (!parent.data("handlersInstalled"))` will be true because the `!` reverses the logic.  This just lets us know whether we've already set the event handlers or not so we don't ever set them a second time for the particular parent that was clicked.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I got that. But I do not find anything on the argument `true`in the `data()` method. Like here `data("handlersInstalled", true)`. ? Thanks!!

Comment: @dollarvar - perhaps you need to read the doc for [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).  `parent.data("handlersInstalled")` reads the current value of the `handlersInstalled` flag.  The `if` statement then checks that value and makes a logic decision based on that value.  In this case the value will be either `undefined` (because it has never been set) or it will be `true` because it has been set.  `.data()` can be used to either read or write the value depending upon whether it is passed one argument or two arguments.  This is very common in jQuery.

Comment: Sorry, I do not want to upset you, but you use here: `data("handlersInstalled", true)` a `true` which is in no word in the doc. And this is not the checking in the `if` statement, this is something you set on "setting" the data value and please read my question right. ;) Thank You!!

Comment: @dollarvar - `true` is a javascript reserved word and is one of the values of a Boolean variable in javascript which can be `true` or `false`.  In this particular case, you could have also set the value to `1` or `"yes"` as all would satisfy the later `if` test when retrieving the variable.  It's like assigning a variable `var flag = true;` in a javascript statement.  As per the jQuery doc `.data( key, value )`, the `true` is the value.

Comment: I just woke up and realised that. ;) Thank you for your efforts in explaining!! See you. ;)