# Is JavaScript (jQuery) and a handler run from memory or read every time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is in two parts. One overall question and one relating to it with explicit code.

The general question:
Is Javascript read into the memory on load, and by this "installed", or is it read each time I do something? How are handlers installed? Once I `.click()` on an element, is then the handler in memory, including the function inside it? I once had trouble with a `.mouseleave()`, every time I left the element, the function was installed again and it was absolute chaos...how does this work with `.click()` then? Is the function then every time read again or does it stay in memory? The solution to the `.mouseleave()` was: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616220/jquery-does-not-run-functions-animate-css-after-second-click-but-console-log).

The specific question:
I just found out, that a `.click()` function I use [here](http://blanc-encens.com/profile) runs on first click once, on the second click twice, etc. ? You can see it, when you open the link, open the console and click on an image. Click on it to close it again, then click on ANY(!!) image and it loads as described. Weird, huh? Also it logs in the `console` the boolean for `.data("installed")` as true, although the switch to true comes only later in code?
Hope you can help me.

jQuery code:

```
$('.pfiles').data("installed", false);
if (!$('.pfiles').data("installed")) {
    $('.pfiles img').click(function() {
        var scroll = $('body').scrollTop(),
            imgThis = $(this).attr('src'),
            txtThis = $(this).attr('src').split('/')[2].split('.')[0] + ".txt",
            $this = $(this),
            bigImgH = $(this).height(),
            bigImgW = $(this).width();
        $('.progress').show();
        console.log($('.pfiles').data("installed"));
        $('.pfiles').fadeOut(200, function() {
            $('.big').fadeIn(400);
            $('.frame').height($('.big').height());
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: imgThis,
            dataType: 'HTML',
            success: function(data) {
                $('.big').empty().append("<img src='" + imgThis + "'/>");

                if (bigImgW / bigImgH <= 1.3529411176) {
                    $('.big img').css({'height': '100%'});
                } else {
                    $('.big img').css('width', '100%');
                }

                $('body').scrollTop(0);
                $('.big img').click(function(){
                    $('.big').fadeOut(400, function() {
                        $('.pfiles').fadeIn(400);
                        $('body').scrollTop(scroll);
                        $('.big').empty();
                        $('.frame').height($('.incontent').height());
                    }); 
                });
                // progress();
            }
        });
    });
    $('.pfiles').data("installed", true);
}
```

"HTML" code

```
<?php
//Profile catch
$path = 'img/profile';
$profiles = scandir($path);
natsort($profiles);
$profiles = array_reverse($profiles);
$profiles = array_diff($profiles, array('.', '..', '.DS_Store', 'txt'));
?>

<div class="incontent" style="background:white">
<div class="progress">
    <div class="bardiv">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <p class="bartext text"></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="big"></div>
<div class="pfiles">
    <?php
        foreach ($profiles as $pfiles) {
            echo '<img onclick="" src="img/profile/'.$pfiles.'">';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

I already tried the same trick with the `.data()`, but it keeps console.logging on every click (even true!) and it is to no avail to the multiple XHR load... (On the server it is without the `.data()` switch!)

Comment: If you keep on attaching the same event, of course it will happen more than once...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol But where am I doing this?

Comment: Do you have more than one `.pfiles`  or `.big` object in the page?

Comment: Every time you click on `.pfiles img`, you make an ajax call, right? And in that ajax call's success handler, you define an event handler on all `.big img`. This is an example of event handlers creating more event handlers, and you should always be extremely careful to avoid explosive handlers.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Jfriend00 pointed out, that the handler is every time killed, since I `.empty()` the div with the handler. Which is another mystery for me!! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript code in your page is parsed and run at the time the page loads and remains in memory in the browser while the page is active.  As the user interacts with the page, any event handlers that your code might have installed are then called upon demand as those events happen.

Once you install a `.click()` handler, it remains in place for the lifetime of that DOM element or until you remove the click handler.  Until you remove it, the click handler will get called every time the item is clicked on.

You should ONLY install a `.click()` handler for a given function one time.  If you install it multiple times, it will be called multiple times when the item is clicked.  If your click handler is being called more and more times each time you click it, then your code is apparently installing another click handler each time you click on it and you would need to modify your code not to do that.

To help more specifically, we'd need to know which click handler you're having an issue with and probably need to see some of the relevant HTML.

---

You can simplify your event handling code by having only one constant event handler for the `.big img` rather than constantly creating a new one.  You can do that with delegated event handling like this:

```
$(".big").on("click", "img", function() {
    $(".big").fadeOut(400, function() {
        $('.pfiles').fadeIn(400);
        $('body').scrollTop(scroll);
        $('.big').empty();
        $('.frame').height($('.incontent').height());
    }); 
});
```

Put this code before any of the code you have in your question so it is initialized once and only once.

---

Here's a potential problem.  At the very beginning of your block of code, you have this:

```
$('.pfiles').data("installed", false);
if (!$('.pfiles').data("installed")) {
```

That means that you will ALWAYS execute the `if` block, even if you previously set the data to `true`.  You can just remove the first line because the default value for `$('.pfiles').data("installed")` will be falsey.  You don't need to initialize it.  Then, when this is called subsequent times, it will respect the fact that you've set it to `true` later in your code.

Comment: So what happens when I click twice on a `.click()` handler element. Will the function content be installed then twice also? Does that not stack up?

Comment: @dollarvar - each time you click on the element, the click handler will be called unless the click handler either removes the DOM element that has the click handler attached or removes the click handler.

Comment: Code added! I have problems with the, eeeh, actually I do not know which handler is causing this. The `.pfiles img` or `.big img` handler?!? You tell me.

Comment: So why did I have problems with the `.mouseleave` and subsequent additional handler (function) installations? To the first part of the question: Is the whole javascript code in memory on load or read and interpreted on action, everytime I click?

Comment: Ok, I just read the edited part wholly of your answer. So the problem is, that I install a `.click()` handler every time the `$.ajax` succeeds?! Arrgh, I see. Let me try it.

Comment: No, it's not. Now I have an: `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation `. It closes the image though, but on click on another image, nothing happens, hmmm. And it is still stacking the calls up as described, hmmm. :/

Comment: @dollarvar - I can't help with your modified code without seeing what you changed.  I'm not sure your click handler in the ajax success handler was a problem because you are removing the element that it was on when you did `$(".big").empty()` which would also remove the event handler.  You can make all of that a lot simpler with one delegated event handler that stays the whole time.  I will add that to the end of my answer.

Comment: @dollarvar - see the potential problem I just found that I added to the end of my answer.

Comment: Looked promising, though I have to learn know what you did in every case. ;) It is not working! I do not know if you saw the link in my question, but if you go to http://blanc-encens.com/profile and click several times on the images with open console you will know what I mean. I added your code, it is live now! Thanks!!

Comment: Addition: When I do this in front of all the code I posted, I again get the `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`, I can click on an image, everything runs twice, but no big image appears anymore! :/

Comment: @dollarvar - what is not working?  I go to your live site and click on an image, it shows a large version.  Click on it again, it goes back to showing multiple images, repeat over and over with no errors and no loss of function.

Comment: Please open the console and see the subsequent adding calls. It is not THAT bad like this, but I want to add text with `ajax` under the images later and this call will be done several times also...adds up to several copies of the text!!

Comment: @dollarvar - per my recent comment and what I added to the end of my answer a little while ago, you need to remove this line of your code `$('.pfiles').data("installed", false);`.

Comment: Ah, I just saw your other potential problem. Yes it works with the first line deleted!!! But just because it is in an `.ajaxStop()` block, right? On a normal basis it is not set every time to false, is it? This would lead to the question again if JS is read every time I run an action!?! Thanks!!! This could be the whole answer to the question...every time I stop an `ajax` call, the handler gets installed again, yikes.

Comment: @dollarvar - I already answered the part about when JS is read (once when the page loads) at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: But why does it get set to false then with the wrong line of code in it every time before I click, if I may ask? Would you like to go with me into the chat? Eaah, how does that work? :)

Comment: @dollarvar - You appear to be executing this code every time `preAfter()` is called which is once during initialization and then again after every ajax call.  Because you're calling this code multiple times is why you have to protect against installing the event handlers multiple times.  If you were only running this code once during page initailization, you wouldn't have to protect against this in the first place because the code would only ever run once.

Comment: Wow, you did your digging! Thanks mate for all the dynamic work!! The thing with chat is, I cannot open rooms, poor reputation-related guy. ;) Thanks again!